# Why is the value of array[d] 5?

Tags: java, arrays

Im new to arrays... and i quite having a hard time understanding how arrays works in this CODE only...
i am doing a bubble sort. the only thing i dont understand is that can the variable d be put in a variable array???

```
import java.util.Scanner;

   public class bubbleSort
  {
  public static void main(String []args)
  {
        int n, c, d, swap;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Input number of integers to sort");
        n = in.nextInt();

        int array[] = new int[n];

        System.out.println("Enter " + n + " integers");

        for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
          array[c] = in.nextInt();

        for (c = 0; c < ( n - 1 ); c++)
        {
              for (d = 0; d < n - c - 1; d++)
              {
                if (array[d] > array[d+1])
                {
                    System.out.println("array d:" + array[d]); // value is 5
                  swap       = array[d];
                  array[d]   = array[d+1];
                  array[d+1] = swap;
                }
             }
        }

        System.out.println("Sorted list of numbers");

        for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
          System.out.println(array[c]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a variable when it is in loop. That `d` variable will be assigned a numerical value.In your case every time loop runs `d` will have value starting from 0 to n-c-1 which will make array[0],array[1]..... so this will illustrated as by following example:
suppose you have an array called :

```
int[] array={1,2,3,4,5};
```

so when you loop this array using for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i< 5; i++)
          system.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

every time loop run the array will be like

```
array[0] 
array[1]
array[2]
array[3]
array[4]
```

and it prints value like

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

respectively
This shows that variable `i` is not considered a variable rather it is a numerical value

Answer (score 0):

Array's Indexes are starting from `0` to length-1 of array. so index can have only numerical values (integer).
if you are doing like below it will not work (**long,float,double**)

```
    long c=1;
    int arr[]={1,2,3};
    System.out.println(arr[c]);//this will not work as index is long
```

and if you are putting any index variable compatible to **int (short,byte,char)**, you will be able to fetch the value from array.

```
     int c=1;
    int arr[]={1,2,3};
    System.out.println(arr[c]);// this will work fine and print element at index 1 and that is 2
```

output will be 2 for latter code.